# Eclipse debug not entering method

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have two method calls -

```
boolean firstNameMatches = firstNameMatches(firstName, object1);
boolean lastNameMatches = lastNameMatches(lastName, object2);
```

Both methods looks something like this -

```
public boolean firstNameMatches(String firstName, Class1 object1)
{
        boolean nameMatches = false;

        if (StringUtil.isBlankAfterTrim(firstName)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Some code here
        }
}
```

I am trying to debug these in eclipse - running on tomcat. When the breakpoint hits either method call, and I press F5 to step into, it enters the method call to `StringUtil.isBlankAfterTrim(firstName)` instead of the called methods own code. Please advise how to actually debug inside either of the methods. Also, I am not seeing values returned from the method call after it is returned.

Thanks

Comment: @Jean-Francois, thanks for the edit...somehow, I could not get it into one block

Comment: would you, per chance, have optimizations enabled? `-XX:+AggressiveOpts`, for instance, that would explain what you're seeing. Also, try to add some `System.out.println` lines at the start of your function. It may not be optimized out in that case.